# Powershell -NoNewWindow acting not as expected

Tags: powershell, windows-10

When I do:

```
Start powershell -NoNewWindow
```

I get the following behavior. Leaving the cursor where it was, I typed "Testing" 3 times. Notice how it alternated between the top and bottom half of the screen. Is this a bug or is this an expected behavior due to something I've missed?

[image]

Comment: My best guess is that you've got two PowerShell sessions attached to the same console, which leads to undesirable behavior. What are you trying to accomplish? I have never needed to start PowerShell this way.

Comment: Why are you trying to launch powershell when you're already in powershell?

Comment: I wanted to use the -Verb RunAs to get it going as admin. Or get it running with other credentials specified. I decided to strip it of any extra arguments to see why I'm getting that behavior

I'm only opening powershell once. And running that command right after

Comment: @Fexception Dan Wilson is right. After that command you have two PowerShell instances connected to the same console window and competing for user input from it. Thus you are getting such weird behavior. BTW, `-Verb` is not compatible with `-NoNewWindow`.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl , Do you know what the use of such a command would be? If that's how the command behaves, then why would anyone want to use it? Whats it there for? Just trying to learn more :)

Comment: You can use it like this: `start PowerShell -NoNewWindow; exit` — to restart PowerShell session in the same window, for example.